# Members of Java array class

Tags: java

Reflexion API shows that any Java array class implements interface java.lang.Cloneable  and java.io.Serializable. It does not have any member declared.

My questions are:

- Where this 'length' is defined?
- Where the  protected Object clone() is overridden with public access
  specifier using co-variant return type(byte[] replacing Object) as we
  can directly assign it to a byte[]?
- Where the association(IS-A) with Cloneable and Serializable is
  defined?

Also access specifier for the byte[] class contains "abstract final" which is not a legal combination of any class or method in Java.

```
    import java.lang.reflect.*;

    public class ArrayExplorer {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
      explore("Current class:", byte[].class);

      byte[] bytes = { 65, 'A' };
      System.out.println(bytes.length);

      byte[] cloned = bytes.clone();
      System.out.println(cloned);

   }

private static void explore(String msg, Class<?> class1) {
    if (class1 == null)
        return;

    System.out.println("**************************************\n" + msg
            + Modifier.toString(class1.getModifiers()) + " " + class1);

    // if (class1 == Object.class)
    // return;
    Field[] fields = class1.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        System.out.println(field);
    }

    Method[] methods = class1.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        System.out.println(method);
    }

    explore("Superclass:", class1.getSuperclass());
    explore("Classes:", class1.getClasses());
    explore("ComponentType:", class1.getComponentType());
    explore("DeclaredClasses:", class1.getDeclaredClasses());
    explore("DeclaringClass:", class1.getDeclaringClass());
    explore("EnclosingClass:", class1.getEnclosingClass());

    if (!class1.isInterface()) {
        explore("Interfaces:", class1.getInterfaces());
    }

}

private static void explore(String msg, Class<?>[] classes) {
    if (classes == null || classes.length == 0)
        return;
    System.out.println(msg);
    for (Class<?> class1 : classes) {
        explore("", class1);
    }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaDoc

```
getDeclaredMethods
```

Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private fields, but excludes inherited fields. The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order. **This method returns an array of length 0 if the class or interface declares no fields, or if this Class object represents a primitive type, an array class, or void.**

```
getDeclaredMethods
```

Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private fields, but excludes inherited fields. The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order. **This method returns an array of length 0 if the class or interface declares no fields, or if this Class object represents a primitive type, an array class, or void.**

Answer (score 0):

An array in java is a bit like a primitive: Although there is an `Array.class` to represent it, it doesn't really have "code", because the type is built right into the language, so its fields like `length` etc aren't accessible by reflection.

Comment: I heard the native code was exposed by Java (openJDK?), can we find the "code" there?